# change soap adress in generated wsdl file

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

> I want to change the URL in generated wsdl file,

**I Have an application developped in JEE and then I generate wsdl file, however the URL in generated file not securised,**

[image]

**when I put the url of the wsdl in the navigator, the file is generated and I can show the contenu, but when I use the same URL in API PHP or Java, I get an error**

```
    <wsdl:service name="CleverSMSUser">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:CleverSMSUserSoapBinding" name="CleverSMSUserImplPort">
<soap:address location="http://services.*****:8080/******/ws/user"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

**So I want to change the soap adress  as follow (of course in ssl)**

```
<wsdl:service name="CleverSMSUser">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:CleverSMSUserSoapBinding" name="CleverSMSUserImplPort">
<soap:address location="https://services*****fr:8443/****/ws/user"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

**when I run my code in PHP API I get this error**

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://services.******/cleversms/ws/user?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://services.*******:8443/******/ws/user?wsdl" 
</wsdl:service>
```

**My code in PHP as follow**

```
try{
    //$ms = ServiceProvider::get('user');

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
    ));

    $ms=new SoapClient(
        'https://*******/*****/ws/user?wsdl',
        array(
            // Stuff for development.
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => true,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_depth'      => 0,
            // Auth credentials for the SOAP request.
                'login' => 'majdi',
                'password' => 'majdi',


        )
);

    $credit = $ms->getCreditsLeft();
    echo "credit: ".$credit;

}
```

notice than when I use the HTTP url (not HTTPS), the code work fine without any problem

I use JBOSS 6.01

Any Help Please to resolve this problems

Comment: it is better to share your code

Comment: @KhalilM I shared my code in php, the problems is in using https adress not http. If I use an URL with http every thing work fine, but when  I use HTTPS adress, I get an error. but also when I put the HTTPS adress in chrome , I can display the contents of the wsdl file

Comment: what happend with manual curl?